# Tracking files using heroku and/or github

Tags: git, heroku

I have created an heroku app and I am deploying it using Github. (all well so far)

I chose to deploy through Github so that I could see the most updated version of my files because I wasn't able to see this on the Heroku website.
Though when running (for example)

`git add .
 git commit -m "new update"` 
`git push heroku master`

Everything gets deployed to Heroku but my Github repository is not being updated. 
I can't see any of the committed changes and was wondering why.
Do I need to push the files to my Github repository in addition to pushing the files to heroku or why are they otherwise not being pushed to Github when I use "git push heroku master"?

Comment: Because you’re pushing to heroku not GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need indeed to commit/push your code (and any file) to GitHub, this is your master copy. Heroku, once connected to your GitHub account, will use the very latest version you push to GitHub.
You can also enable Automated Deployment if you like, so each push trigger a build/deploy.

Beppe